# Can the HTML5 Audio Player be configured to persist through page loads?

Tags: html, audio

Apologies if this is a bit vague but I'm wondering if it would be possible to have the HTML5 audio player continue playing while navigating through various pages on the same site, rather than stopping and starting with each page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. When you leave a page, everything gets torn down. You can *store* things in local or session storage, but DOM components, open connections, the in-memory data your were working with etc. get lost.

Your realistic option is to design a [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) where a user's navigation event does not correspond to the browser's one, and, in the ideal case, there is no browser navigation event. This way the audio player will be active for as long as the user is on your website.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't something I'd be able to do as this is a simple embedded file on a platform site. Thank you for answering the question nonetheless.